# rails3 authlogic admin roles

Tags: ruby-on-rails, authlogic

I have authlogic working fine but now have the need to let administrator users come in and have different access.

So I created a migration adding `administrator` column to the `Users` table as string.  However, I just can not seem to get the value of it out!!

see below my index action:

```
print "\n administrator" + User.find(current_user.id).administrator.to_s
```

the above line never prints anything when I know that this user HAS `administrator` string set to `true` in the db.

Below is the User model

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  acts_as_authentic  {|config| 
    config.validates_uniqueness_of_email_field_options :scope => :id
  }
  belongs_to :another_class
end
```

what am I doing wrong here?  All I want to do is get the administrator column value out.  In the logs I can see the `select users.* from users where id = 2` query being run!

is there another best way to manage admin roles with authlogic??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're likely better off using [cancan](https://github.com/ryanb/cancan) for managing roles and permissions.  It can be used in combination with authlogic.

If you are going to just add a flag "administrator" field to the user record, it should work as long as your rules are simple, but would be better as a boolean rather than a string.

Answer (score 0):

You say you have an "administrator" column of strings in your database and you're looking for a value of true. Maybe you wanted a Boolean column?